# Can't override the opacity value?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a fixed `div` overlay (whole screen) which contain another smaller centered `div` for a message.

The big div has `position:fixed` and opacity.

The inner div also has `position:fixed` but without opacity

But in the **inner** `div` , I don't want to have any transparency.(`opacity: 1`) :

**Problem:**

I still see it as transparent.  How can I fix it ( the inner div) ?

[image]

the inner div background-color is black. and the color is red. and (as you can see) it is not what is happening. ( I also tried !important)

[**Full JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/icuXOrI/3/edit)

NB

the overlay div and inner div should not be scrolled when user scrolls.

Comment: Use `RGBA` as background color instead of `opacity`: http://jsbin.com/icuXOrI/4/edit

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek works. thank you. (p.s. what's the difference ?) and please post it as an answer.

Comment: Once you set an opacity, all child element's opacities will only range from 0 to the outer elements opacity. So, if you set, 0.5 on the outer element and 1 on the inner element, the end result will be 0.5 for the inner elements. Or 0.5 on the inner would result in 0.25 opacity.

Comment: @Yoshi **Very** reasonable. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the background color transparant by using `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`

Comment: I actually prefer this method to dragoste's as HTML structure is extremely important (imo) and if you can do it while retaining good structure, then do it that way

Answer (score 3):

Just put the non-opacity div outside of the div with opacity.

http://jsbin.com/icuXOrI/11/edit?html,js,output

It has `position:fixed` so I doesn't matter where you put it.

Comment: who has position:absolute ?

Comment: But then If I want to hide the div+overlay , i need to hide 2 elements instead of one .

Comment: You could add a 3th div to contain the other 2, and then show/hide that one.

Answer (score 0):

Keep two different divs, one with less opacity and other without.

```
<div parent>
    <div with opacity></div>
    <div without opacity></div>
</div>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/icuXOrI/24/edit)